# Graphing Parabolas Word Problem

Tags: graphing-functions, quadratics

A flying cannonball’s height is described by formula $y=−16t^2+300t$. Find the highest point of its trajectory. In how many seconds after the shot will cannonball be at the highest point? What is the highest point?

I tried finding the vertex but it does not seem to help me. I know how to graph it, but I just don't know how to use it. Thanks!

Comment: I would normally use differentiation to find the maximum.  But from a graph you just pick the highest value it reached and inspect the t value at that point, so I am not sure what your problem is.

Answer (score 0):

The $t$ coordinate of your vertex answers the first question, and the $y$ coordinate answers the second question. I assume your work looked like this:

$$y=-16t^2+300t$$

$$y'=-32t+300$$

$$0=-32t+300$$

$$t=9.375^{*}$$

$$y=-16(9.375)^2+300(9.375)$$

$$y=1406.25^{**}$$

*Answer to first question

**Answer to second question

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use derivatives, you may recall from your class that the value of the $t$-coordinate of the vertex of the equation $y = at^2+bt+t$ is $\frac{-b}{2a}$ (using calculus, you simply just derive that expression rather than take it for granted). So in this problem, the $x$-coordinate of the vertex is $\frac{-300}{-32} = 9.375$

Plugging that in you get $y = -16(9.375)^2 + 300(9.375) = 1406.25$.